# Soap Service Model Binding failure

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, soap, model-binding

I have a WCF Soap Service . there is a method with a model parameter in it

like this :

`public FirPrpsRes RegPrps(FirPrpsReq PrpsReq)`

`FirPrpsReq` model has a List of another model

> ```
> public class FirPrpsReq
> {
>   public int id{get; set;}
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   public List<FirPlcyInsrd> PlcyInsrd { get; set; }
> }
> ```

When i call this mothod from soapUI some properties in `FirPlcyInsrd` doesn't bind;
all of them are *null*.

Property names are same as model in soapui and values are correct

Please Help!

**update**

I sort properties Alphabetical in SoapUi request and it is working
but our customers do not send request like this and they receive error

Why Sorting Alphabetical is matter?

Comment: When you use collections polymorphically in place of non-collection types, they must be added to known types. For example, if you declare a data member of type Object and use it to send an instance of ArrayList, add ArrayList to known types. For more information about "Collections and Known Types", you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/collection-types-in-data-contracts

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize your model by adding an attribute from the System.Runtime.Serialization in order to expose your model into the wcf service.

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization
[DataContract]
public class FirPrpsReq
{
  [DataMember]
  public int id{get; set;}
  [DataMember]
  public List<FirPlcyInsrd> PlcyInsrd { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your attention @edisket . i tested your solution but any change.

Comment: @Ali Maleki , did you serialize the class **FirPlcyInsrd**  using the System.Runtime.Serialization?

Comment: Yes, I do.*FirPlcyInsrd  and All Childs